# Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on init

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I installed the FacebookConnect plugin into my cordova project with the code:

```
cordova -d plugin add /Users/your/path/here/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
```

Then linked the Facebook API (3.8.0) in /platforms/android/project.properties with:

```
android.library.reference.2=../../facebook-android-sdk-3.8.0/facebook
```

Then copied the example 'Simple' into the /www folder, added my app id and changed phonegap.js to cordova.js.

When I compile and run the application on my android phone I receive the following errors:

```
Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on init
Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on auth.status
```

and on login:

```
Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on login!Class not found
```

LogCat gives the following error:

```
exec() call to unknown plugin: org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect
```

I've scoured the internet but cannot find a solution to this problem.

I did notice that my /platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml file lists the plugin as:

```
<feature name="FacebookConnectPlugin">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin" />
</feature>
```

When the Documentation says that it should be:

```
<feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
    <param name="ios-package" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
</feature>
```

But I can't change this as it's automatically generated during the compiling process.

Comment: You miscopied the `name="ios-package"` should be android, And you can change the the `<feature>`. just paste it on `config.xml` and build and run.

Comment: Hi there, Did you figure this one out? same here

Comment: I never got it working, ended up using this plugin: http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/04/facebook-phonegap-cordova-without-plugin/

As far as I can tell this plugin is buggy and has no decent support.

Comment: If there is a bug, report it [here](https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB), where it's being supported.

Comment: @Alastair I think user3509611 might be implying the official plugin is buggy and yours is instead a better alternative - hard to tell from the comment

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I did in fact mean the official plugin was buggy. @Alastair, the OpenFB plugin works perfectly.

Comment: Ahh - understood! I'm glad to hear it, @Pierowheelz :)

Comment: The sad part is this plug-in works STELLAR on the Phonegap Build process... so sad to see it being this much of a hassle as we move to local build process.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to copy (from the download) www/cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js, www/facebook-js-sdk.js into your apps www folder?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, managed to fix by updating my **root** config.xml (which isn't generated) to include:

```
<feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin" />
</feature>
```

(Note **android**-package as looks like you are using android.)

This is under the [*manual* install section](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin#manual-android-installation) of the readme, but also seems to be necessary after following the [automatic install process](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin#automatic-installation).

Now you can execute `cordova build android` from the root, bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

As of 6/13/14 this is what works for me, so I laid out my steps on PasteBin.
http://pastebin.com/WvQvqx6U

Basically just reverted back to 0.4.0 of Facebook Connect.
It's working perfectly for me, and I didn't have any issues setting it up.